# Running a python script with nose.run(...) from outside of the script's directory results in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'

Tags: python, nose

I have a python application with a few sub directories. Each subdirectory has its own `tests.py` file.

I use nose to run all of the unittests across all of these files in one shot, by creating a script `run_unit_tests.py` that calls `nose.run(...)`.

If I am inside of the directory containing `run_unit_tests.py`, everything works fine. However, if I am anywhere else on the file system, it fails with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'.

Here is something similar to my directory structure:

```
MyApp/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        tests.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
            tests.py
    run_unit_tests.py
```

In my `run_unit_tests.py`:

```
class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.run(argv=['', 'foo.tests', '--with-my-plugin'])
    nose.run(argv=['', 'foo.bar.tests', '--with-my-plugin'])
```

If I run `run_unit_tests.py` while inside the top `MyApp` directory, everything works fine.

However, if I run the script while in some other folder on the file system, it fails with:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'tests')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 407, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "/apps/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 322, in resolve_name
    obj = getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'
```

---

In fact, if I add the following to `run_unit_tests.py`, it works fine:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/MyApp')
```

What can I change inside of my nose script such that I can run the script from outside of the directory?

Comment: My comment was too long, so I formulated as an answer. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want to be careful here. Because, the reason why this is happening is because your imports in your test are with respect to: `/path/to/MyApp`.

So, when you run your tests from that working directory, your unit test files are all importing with respect to that directory being the project source. If you change directories and run from another location, that now becomes your root, and your imports will surely fail.

This could bring different opinions, but I usually make sure my sources are all referenced from the same project root. So if we are here:

```
MyApp/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        tests.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
            tests.py
    run_unit_tests.py
```

I would run everything from within `MyApp`

Furthemore, I would consider creating a `tests` directory and putting all your tests in that directory, making your imports easier to manage and better segregating your code. However, this is just an opinion, please don't feel like this is a necessity. Whatever works for you, go with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, so I should just run my tests from the root directory, and no where else?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I would say, to make your life easier, yes. TBH, it's just a matter of being aware where you are running your tests and being consistent with that, so that you don't face issues with importing modules from your tests. Furthermore, to support doing things from your project root, if for example, you are to deploy this application to a CI. e.g. Travis, Travis runs w.r.t to the project root (there might be a way to specify where you want it to run, but I just stuck with configuring things at the same level).

Comment: So, that is typically the expectation where your module references should come from. I hope this makes sense. Let me know